# Reaction of acyl chloride with excess Grignard reagent

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, nucleophilic-substitution, organometallic-compounds, grignard-reagent

I have a reaction to which I must find the majority organic product.

[image: The reaction in question]

I think I found the correct product but the fact that the reaction takes two moles of propylmagnesiumbromide confuses me a bit. I added an image of the product I think would be the result.

[image: The product I think it should make]

I would like to know if I found the right product, and if the two moles of propylmagnesiumbromide means that there is a second part to this reaction.

Comment: https://www.chemistrysteps.com/reaction-of-acyl-chlorides-with-grignard-and-gilman-organocuprate-reagents/ This will help you. You can Google 'acyl chloride grignard' for more explanations.

Comment: Your product would exist in the reaction medium as the MgBr alkoxide; it is unstable. You have a second equivalent of Grignard remaining.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but shouldn't the grignard reagent here attack the carbonyl twice and give 4-cyclopropylHeptan-4-ol?

Comment: Cl will leave after the first grignard attack and you get a ketone again. the next eqv. reacts to give a 3 degree alcohol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following paragraph from *Acid Halide Chemistry<sup>[[1]](https://chem.libretexts.org/@go/page/183124)</sup>* sums up the answer to your question:

> Acid chlorides react with Grignard reagents to produce tertiary alcohols. Two equivalents of the Grignard reagent are needed because the first equivalent reacts to form a ketone which then reacts with the second equivalent. Because of the high reactivity of the Grigard reagent, the reaction can NOT be stopped at the ketone.
> [image: Acyl chloride reaction with Grignard reagent]

Coming to your specific case the reaction would proceed with the following mechanism:

[image: Acyl halide + Grignard reagent]

---

**Reference:**

<sup>[(1)](https://chem.libretexts.org/@go/page/183124) Acid Halide Chemistry https://chem.libretexts.org/@go/page/183124 (accessed May 24, 2021).</sup>

Comment: To prevent dehydration of this product (because it is a *tertiary* alcohol) keep in mind that a neutralization (during workup) with an aqueous solution of $\ce{NH4Cl}$ may be safer than the addition of $\ce{HCl}$.

Comment: @Buttonwood I absolutely agree with you on that.

Comment: Grignard reagents aren't ionic salts, they don't have a negative charge, so technically the arrow should be drawn from the C–Mg bond.